# If clicked on class do this, else this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that opens a dropdown menu.
The dropdown options disappears once you click on an option or off the menu.

I need to try and establish too different functions, one if a menu item is clicked, and other for if a menu item isn't clicked (i.e a different part of the screen).

I have tried to do this by - if object of class contains '.menubtns' do this.. else....

```js
// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];

      /// here is where the behaviour needs to be added //////////
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show') &&
        ($(this.target).hasClass('menubtns'))) {

        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        console.log('you have clicked an option');

      } else {
        console.log('not clicked on an option')
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        mainpageaccessibility();

      }
    }
  }
```

This is so I can set tab orders in a pop-up modal. Currently, it opens the modal but also runs 'mainpageaccessibility();' which then removes all the taborders.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "this" refers to the window object. I think you mean to use "event" there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't test this but it appears you used "this" where you should have used "event"

"this" refers to the window object.

```
// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];

            /// here is where the behaviour needs to be added //////////
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show') &&
                ($(event.target).hasClass('menubtns'))) {

                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                console.log('you have clicked an option');

            } else {
                console.log('not clicked on an option')
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                mainpageaccessibility();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onclick = e => {
   if(e.target.id == "your element id here" ){
    //do something
    }else{
    //do the other thing
    }

} 

function myFunction(event) { 
if(event.target.id == "your element id here" ){
    //do something
    }else{
    //do the other thing
    }
}
```

Edit: Either an arrow function or a normal. Choose what you want

Comment: This is for browser JavaScript which doesn't necessarily support arrow functions and arrow functions are not needed here.

Comment: @PHPGuru While "arrow functions" are a fairly new thing, pretty much every browser (except IE) supports them.  Depending on what clients you wish to support with your website, it may not matter if older browsers don't support this (is any client going to be connecting with an older browser?).  https://caniuse.com/arrow-functions

Comment: arrow functions are not needed here, That you can't argue with.

Comment: @PHPGuru Arrow functions are rarely "needed", but many programmers prefer them because they're more concise.

Comment: @PHPGuru And unless you need to bind `this`, there's little reason not to use them if you like them.

Comment: fair enough but only if minifying your javascript is really that important

Comment: Give me a break, getElementsByClassName has much better support than arrow functions which don't work in IE. Literally millions of people still use IE and other old browsers.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. The current function uses `this`, so an arrow function won't work without some other changes to the code. And the advice seems to be "Add ids to every element and use an enormous if/else block to check for every one of them" which is terrible advice...